# Routing error with angular 2 and IIS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis, angular, angular2-routing

I have an application created with angular 2 that locally works perfectly. But now that I deployed the application in iis when I try to navigate to any route (using the router of angular 2) I get an "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
Any ideas of how to fix this or why I'm getting this error?

This is the server url:
http://vote-ui-app.azurewebsites.net/voting-app-ui
should I change the base url?

This is the routing in the app.component.ts where all the routing is defined:

```
    import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

    import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';
    import 'rxjs/Rx'; // load the full rxjs
    import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig , ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from  'angular2/router';

    import { ResultsComponent } from './results/results.component'
    import { VotingCardsComponent } from     './votingcards/votingcards.component'
    import { DashBoardComponent } from './dash/dash.component'
    import { PollsComponent } from './pollslist/pollslist.component'

    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ResultsComponent, VotingCardsComponent, DashBoardComponent],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
    })

    @RouteConfig([

        { path: '/vote', name: 'VotePage', component: VotingCardsComponent },
        { path: '/votepoll/:id', name: 'VotePoll', component: VotingCardsComponent },
        { path: '/results', name: 'Results', component: ResultsComponent },
        { path: '/polls', name: 'Polls', component: PollsComponent },
        { path: '/', name: 'DashBoard', component: DashBoardComponent, useAsDefault: true }
    ])

    export class AppComponent { }
```

And this is my main.ts where I configure the base url:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

//this is to avoid the href empty issue
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    //this is to avoid the href empty issue
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue : '/' })
]);
```

Comment: Check if you have provided the right paths to each component.

Comment: That's not a lot of information. What `LocationStrategy` are you using. What URL did you enter. What route should id match?

Comment: When I navigate I don't use a hash so I think is PathLocationStrategy