# Hash Location Strategy in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to create an application with hash location strategy, but it does not add the hash to the url. For instance when I click on a button associated with { path: '/polls', name: 'Polls', component: PollsComponent } it loads the page with this url : localhost:3000/polls.

What do I have to change to get the hash location strategy?
Why do I have to set the default base url if I want to use hash location strategy?

This is the routing in the app.component.ts where all the routing is defined:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx'; // load the full rxjs
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig , ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from  'angular2/router';

import { ResultsComponent } from './results/results.component'
import { VotingCardsComponent } from     './votingcards/votingcards.component'
import { DashBoardComponent } from './dash/dash.component'
import { PollsComponent } from './pollslist/pollslist.component'

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ResultsComponent, VotingCardsComponent, DashBoardComponent],
providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

@RouteConfig([

    { path: '/vote', name: 'VotePage', component: VotingCardsComponent },
    { path: '/votepoll/:id', name: 'VotePoll', component: VotingCardsComponent },
    { path: '/results', name: 'Results', component: ResultsComponent },
    { path: '/polls', name: 'Polls', component: PollsComponent },
    { path: '/', name: 'DashBoard', component: DashBoardComponent, useAsDefault: true }
])

export class AppComponent { }
```

And this is my main.ts where I configure the base url:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

//this is to avoid the href empty issue
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

    bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    //this is to avoid the href empty issue
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' })

]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ROUTER_PROVIDERS` should **not** be added to child components,

**only** to

```
providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
```

**or** alternatively **only** to

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

`HTTP_PROVIDERS` are in my opinion also a better fit for root component or `bootstrap()` but it doesn't break anything to add them somewhere else.

(See also [Routing error with angular 2 and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427256/routing-error-with-angular-2-and-iis))

Answer (score 43):

You can use the option "useHash" in RouterModule.forRoot().

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});
```

https://discuss.atom.io/t/angular-2-routes-breaking-on-electron-app-refresh/28370/4

Comment: This helped me as this is more suitable for Angular 2 final (I am on 2.2.3). All other answers are for older versions of Angular 2.

Answer (score 4):

Everything worked fine with the sample code OP posted as with what is in the accepted answer. But as a minor note, the format required to changing the Hash Location Strategy in the bootstrap file as of RC.4 goes like this:

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
```

Answer (score -4):

> **It is recommended to use the HTML 5 style (PathLocationStrategy) as location strategy in Angular**

**Because**

1. It produces the clean and SEO Friendly URLs that are easier for users 
   to understand and remember.
2. You can take advantage of the server-side rendering, which will make 
   our application load faster, by rendering the pages in the server 
   first before delivering it the client.

> Use **Hashlocationstrtegy** only if you have to support the older
>   browsers.

[Click Here for More info](https://mahendrawaykos.blogspot.in/2017/12/location-strategies-in-angular-router.html)

Comment: @TRiNE  I don't understand your comment. Mahendra was quoting from online doucmentation. See https://www.netjstech.com/2020/09/location-strategies-in-angular-routing.html. But I do agree the response does not address the OP question directly, but is relevant