# Why angular is adding '#' in each route?

Tags: angular

Angular is adding a '#' in each route I navigate.

I tried to fix it adding the following code in the index.html At the head tag

```
    <base href="/" />
```

Is there any way to take it out?

[image]

Comment: You can turn it off in the RouterModule configuration. Check the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions) useHash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hash Location Strategy in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429097/hash-location-strategy-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2):

You probably are using `HashLocationStrategy`.

[Location strategy documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles)

Check your routing setup

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue.
In the app.module.ts, in the providers section had the following;

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: LocationStrategy,
        useClass: HashLocationStrategy,
    }
]
```

just commenting that code the issue have been fixed

Thanks for helping!